# synchronization of ajax calls issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<deserializedData.forms.length;i++){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../getFormMetaData/",
            cache:false,
            data: {'a':'a'},
            success: getFormMetaDataCallback,
            error: displayAjaxError
        });
    }
```

Can i somehow do ajax calls when current is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery `when` function to wait for your promises.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

A more detailed answer can be found here: [Wait until all jQuery Ajax requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-request-are-done)

To use it with your loop, you have to save the deferred objects returns by jQuery.ajax in an array and pass that array to the jQuery.when function.

```
var deferredResults = [];
deserializedData.forms.forEach(function () {
    var deferredResult = $.ajax({
        ... // use no success or error callbacks here
    });
});
jQuery.when(deferredResults).done(function() {
    // if you don't know how many calls you made, use the function arguments.
    // this line turns the arguments objects into an array you can use safely.
    var results = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)

});
```

Comment: How to use when in for loop?

Comment: `jQuery.when` also takes arrays as arguments, so you can save the results of each call in an array and pass that to the function. I also edited my answer...

Comment: If i have 4 calls why length of results is always 1? but with alert i get 4 objects separated by comma

Comment: found my bad.. results[0].length is 4

Comment: Thank you! I'm used this solution and it's working! :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var ajax_index = 0; // which request we are currently processing
var arr = [ all, ajax, requests ]; // array of data for each request

// Execute a request
function doRequest( index ){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: arr[ index ]
    ...
    success: function(){
      // Once the request has responded, increase the index counter
      // and execute the next request
      ajax_index++;
      if ( ajax_index > arr.length ){
        // Continue executing requests if there are still remaining
        doRequest( ajax_index );
      }
    }
  });
}
doRequest( ajax_index );
```

By wrapping your AJAX request with a function, you can call this function multiple times each time with a different index in order to execute all of the requests sequentially.